# Unexpected character Â in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug, jade4j

Whats wrong in the jade template below.

When i tried to find out by converting the jade to html, i get error as unexpected Â

```
extends layout

block content 
.container 
h1 Register Page 
p.lead Say something worthwhile here. 
br 
form(role='form', action="/register",method="post", style='max-width: 300px;')
    .form-group 
    input.form-control(type='text', name="username", placeholder='Enter Username')
    .form-group 
    input.form-control(type='password', name="password", placeholder='Password') 
    button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
    Â
    a(href='/')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type="button") Cancel 
    br 
    h4 info
```

[image]

My design looks something like:

[image]

I am using pug for VS code to beautify the code and format it.

Comment: There's an 'Â' in your Jade template... am I missing something?

Comment: yes i m following this link which uses the  'Â'  in their jade.. http://www.bogotobogo.com/MEAN-Stack/MEAN-Stack-MongoDB-ExpressJS-AngularJS-NodeJS-Authentication-Passport-App.php    and if i remove the  'Â' i get "no such file or directory, open .../layout.pug' at line 1

Comment: I'm no Jade/Pug expert, so I might be completely wrong, but that looks like a typo to me. I can't find any reference to using 'Â' in the docs. The error you're seeing once you remove it might be genuine. Do you have a layout.pug file?

Comment: If you've installed `pug`, but created `layout.jade` as that blog suggests, rather than `layout.pug` then that could be causing that error.

Comment: Ok thanks for the inputs, let me verify